# MassTransit - random mediator response not consumed

Tags: c#, masstransit

So one in a hundred (Mediator)messages does not get consumed and I can't figure out why.
Messages sent via rabbitMq are fine.

Exception:

```
"InnerException": {
    "Type": "MassTransit.MessageNotConsumedException",
    "Uri": "loopback://localhost/response",
    "TargetSite": "System.Threading.Tasks.Task Send(MassTransit.ReceiveContext, GreenPipes.IPipe`1[MassTransit.ReceiveContext])",
    "Message": "loopback://localhost/response => The message was not consumed",
    "Data": {},
    "Source": "MassTransit",
    "HResult": -2146233088
}
```

So whats happening. I have an API that uses both Mediator and RabbitMQ. Everything works most of the time. I register both in a startUp class like this:

```
        services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UsingRabbitMq(ConfigureRabbitMq);
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        services.AddMediator(cfg => 
        { 
            cfg.AddMediatorHandlers();
        });

        ....

    public void ConfigureRabbitMq(IBusRegistrationContext context, IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        var rabbitConfig = RabbitMqConfig.Get<RabbitMqConfiguration>();

        configurator.Host(rabbitConfig.Host, rabbitConfig.VirtualHost , hfg => 
        {
            hfg.Password(rabbitConfig.Password);
            hfg.Username(rabbitConfig.UserName);
        });
    }
```

Now in my controller, when I recieve an request, I pass that via Mediator to an handler that should save the request to database, pass it to rabbitMq and return message if request was saved/sent back to the controller.

Here is controller:

```
    private readonly IRequestClient<CreateCommand> _createProcessor;

    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateManageServicesRequest([FromBody] CreateRequest request)
      {
        try
        {
            var result = await _createProcessor.GetResponse<CreateResponse>(new CreateCommand() { ApiRequest = request});

            if (result.Message.Queued.HasValue)
                return Ok();
            else
                return Accepted();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed httpRequest for {methodName}", nameof(CreateManageServicesRequest));
            return StatusCode((int)StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Heres the handler where exception happens:

```
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateCommand> context)
    {
        var endpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"exchange:{rabbitOptions.ManageServiceQueueName}"));

        using (var sql = sqlFactory.Cip)
        {
            /*SAVE REQUEST TO DATABASE*/
            sql.StartTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);

            .... /* Not important for stack-overflow, just saving request to database */

            sql.Commit();

            /* QUEUE REQUEST*/
            try
            {
                    /*Queue via Rabbit MQ*/
                    await endpoint.Send(new SendCommand() { QueuedRequest = request }, context.CancellationToken);

                    /* Send response ---- THIS FAILS RANDOMLY ---- */
                    await context.RespondAsync(new CreateResponse() { Queued =  DateTimeOffset.Now });
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "ManageServiceRequest", transactionId } }))
                    logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to queque manage service request");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no idea how to solve this and I did not find any relevant information on the MassTransit web or Git.

Comment: I fail to see any MediatR code in those snippets you provided.

Comment: Masstransit implements its own mediator

Comment: So, it's not MediatR? In your question, you mention "mediatr", hence the confusion.

Comment: Is the failing request reaching the default timeout value (30s)?

Comment: Hello Chris, I'l try replicate the problem to see if that is the issue. I have not considered timeout to even be valid on mediator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in the scope. I didnt add the Middleware for getting the scope for controllers. As writtent here: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html

Since adding the AddHttpContextAccessor, the problem is gone.