# MassTransit Mediator MessageNotConsumedException

Tags: masstransit

I Noticed a weird issue in one of our applications, from time to time, we get `MessageNotConsumedException` errors on API requests which we route via MT's Mediator.

As you will notice below, we have configured a customer `LogFilter<T>` which implements `IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>` which ensure that we log each mediator message before and after consuming, or a 'ConsumeFailed' log in case an exception is thrown in any consumer.

When the error manifests itself, in the logs we see the following sequence of events:

```
T 0   : PreConsume logged
T +5ms: PostConsume logged
T +6ms: R-FAULT logged (I believe this logging is made by MT's internals?)
T +9ms: API Request 500 response logged, with `MessageNotConsumedException` as internal error
```

In the production environment, we see these errors with various timings, it happens in requests taking as 'little' as 9ms, over several seconds up to 30+ seconds.

I've trying to reproduce this problem in my local development environment, and did manage to produce the same sequence of events, but only by adding a delay of 35 seconds inside the consumer (see `GetSomethingById` class below for consumer body)
If I reduce the delay to 30s or less, the reponse will be fine.
Since the production errors are happening with very low handling times in the consumer, I suspect what I'm able to reproduce is not exactly the same.
However I'd still like to understand why I'm getting the `MessageNotConsumedException`, since while debugging I can easily step through my entire consumer (after the delay has elapsed) and happily reach the `context.RespondAsync()` call without any problems. Also while stepping through the consumer, the `context.CancellationToken` has not been cancelled.

I also came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69008674/masstransit-random-mediator-response-not-consumed), which sounds exactly like what I'm having, however I did add the HttpContext scope as documented. To be fair, I didn't try this change in production yet, but my local issue with the 35s delay remains unchanged.

I have MassTransit medatior configured as follows:

```cs
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddMediator(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<GetSomethingByIdHandler>();

    x.ConfigureMediator((context, cfg) =>
    {
        //The order of using the middleware matters, so don't change this
        cfg.UseHttpContextScopeFilter(context); // Extension method & friends copy/pasted from https://masstransit-project.com/usage/mediator.html#http-context-scope
        cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(LogFilter<>), context);
    });
});
```

The `LogFilter` which is configured is the following class:

```cs
public class LogFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>> where T : class
{
    private readonly ILogger<LogFilter<T>> _logger;

    public LogFilter(ILogger<LogFilter<T>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) => context.CreateScope("log-filter");

    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        LogPreConsume(context);
        try
        {
            await next.Send(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogConsumeException(context, exception);
            throw;
        }

        LogPostConsume(context);
    }

    private void LogPreConsume(ConsumeContext context) => _logger.LogInformation(
        "{MessageType}:{EventType} correlated by {CorrelationId} on {Address}"
        + " with send time {SentTime:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff}",
        typeof(T).Name,
        "PreConsume",
        context.CorrelationId,
        context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress,
        context.SentTime?.ToUniversalTime());

    private void LogPostConsume(ConsumeContext context) => _logger.LogInformation(
        "{MessageType}:{EventType} correlated by {CorrelationId} on {Address}"
        + " with send time {SentTime:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff}"
        + " and elapsed time {ElapsedTime}",
        typeof(T).Name,
        "PostConsume",
        context.CorrelationId,
        context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress,
        context.SentTime?.ToUniversalTime(),
        context.ReceiveContext.ElapsedTime);

    private void LogConsumeException(ConsumeContext<T> context, Exception exception) => _logger.LogError(exception,
        "{MessageType}:{EventType} correlated by {CorrelationId} on {Address}"
        + " with sent time {SentTime:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff}"
        + " and elapsed time {ElapsedTime}"
        + " and message {@message}",
        typeof(T).Name,
        "ConsumeFailure",
        context.CorrelationId,
        context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress,
        context.SentTime?.ToUniversalTime(),
        context.ReceiveContext.ElapsedTime,
        context.Message);
}
```

I then have a controller method which looks like this:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomethingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

 public SomethingController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet("{somethingId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething([FromRoute] int somethingId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var query = new GetSomethingByIdQuery(somethingId);

        var response = await _mediator
            .CreateRequestClient<GetSomethingByIdQuery>()
            .GetResponse<Something>(query, ct);

        return Ok(response.Message);
    }
}
```

The consumer which handles this request is as follows:

```cs
public record GetSomethingByIdQuery(int SomethingId);

public class GetSomethingByIdHandler : IConsumer<GetSomethingByIdQuery>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<GetSomethingByIdQuery> context)
    {
        await Task.Delay(35000, context.CancellationToken);
        await context.RespondAsync(new Something{Name = "Something cool"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MessageNotConsumedException` is thrown when a message is *sent* using mediator and that message is not consumed by a consumer. That wouldn't typically be a *transient* error since one would expect that the consumer remains configured/connected to the mediator for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: I agree, although I did notice that the `MessageNotConsumedException` is also thrown when the returned message (whatever is passed to `context.RespondAsync()`) is different from what has been specified as `TResponse` in `_mediator.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>().GetResponse<TResponse>()`, is that expected?  

Any idea why the exception could be thrown when a long delay is happening in the consumer?

Comment: Any message type not consumed is going to throw. If you are responding in a consumer, you should be using `IsResponseAccepted<T>` to see if that type is expected.

Comment: OK, clear, thanks! However that still doesn't explain why the `MessageNotConsumedException` is thrown when I add a long delay to the consumer. When removing only that delay, all else being equal, the exception is not thrown.

Comment: No, instead you get a `RequestTimeoutException` because it exceeded the timeout.

Comment: That is indeed what I would expect, but that's not what's happening: As explained in my original question, I am getting a `MessageNotConsumedException` (and not a `RequestTimeoutException`) if I add a long delay in my consumer. Everything else being equal, only removing that delay, fixes the problem.

Comment: Well, if you have a standalone repository that reproduces what you're experiencing, you can create a [discussion](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions) and link it. If it ends up being a bug, an issue will be created. I don't use SO for bug reports.

Comment: Ok, I created a discussion with a reproducible minimal example here: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/3817